# batch script delete files when file name does not match list of patterns

Tags: loops, batch-file, cmd, glob

I want to delete all files in a directory except those whose name matches a certain pattern. A typical example of the kind of files in this directory is as follows:

- Bookmarks.xml ---- *to delete*
- DownloadMeta.xml ---- *to delete*
- logfile.log ---- *to delete*
- 1745388844.idx ---- *to delete*
- TS1.c.pickle ---- *to delete*
- TS1.prm.bak ---- *to delete*
- !clear.bat ---- **keep**
- .gitignore ---- **keep**
- BookFlight.c ---- **keep**
- CheckItinerary.c ---- **keep**
- combined_TS1.c ----**keep**
- pre_cci.c ---- **keep**
- TS1.prm ---- **keep**
- TS1.usr ---- **keep**
- vuser_end.c ---- **keep**
- vuser_init.c ---- **keep**
- globals.h ---- **keep**
- ScriptUploadMetadata.xml ---- **keep**

i want to keep files with names in a list of patterns:

```
list_to_ignore = ["!clear.bat", ".gitignore", "*.usr", "default.cfg", 
                    "default.usp", "*.c", "*lobals.h", "*custom_body.h", 
                    "*body_variables.txt", "*loadMetadata.xml", "*.prm" ]
```

For example:

- file **TS2.c.pickle** does not match any item in the list, because it ends with .pickle extension. It should be deleted.
- file **somefile.c** matches "*.c" pattern, because it ends with .c. It should be kept.
- file **Metadata.xml** does not match any pattern, because it lacks prefix *"load"* at the beginning. It should be deleted.
- file **Globals.h** matches "*lobals.h* pattern. It should be kept.

Here is what I tried:

```
@echo off
FOR /d %%a in ("./*") DO rd "%%a" /q /s
FOR %%i in (*.*) DO ^
if not "%%i"=="!clear.bat" ^
if not "%%i"==".gitignore" ^
if not "%%i"=="*.usr" ^
if not "%%i"=="default.cfg" ^
if not "%%i"=="default.usp" ^
if not "%%i"=="*.c" ^
if not "%%i"=="*lobals.h" ^
if not "%%i"=="*custom_body.h" ^
if not "%%i"=="*body_variables.txt" ^
if not "%%i"=="*ploadMetadata.xml" ^
if not "%%i"=="*.prm" ^
DEL /s /q "%%i"
pause
```

[Here is a list of all files in a local directory with check marks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQKga.png)

Hope this makes sense. If this is not an appropriate question let me know.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done with the following command line in the batch file:

```
@for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0" /A-D /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /X /V /C:"!clear.bat" /C:".gitignore" /C:"BookFlight.c" /C:"CheckItinerary.c" /C:"combined_TS1.c" /C:"pre_cci.c" /C:"TS1.prm" /C:"TS1.usr" /C:"vuser_end.c" /C:"vuser_init.c" /C:"globals.h" /C:"ScriptUploadMetadata.xml" /C:"%~nx0"') do @del /A /F "%~dp0%%I"
```

This command line results in starting one more command process in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line between `'` appended as additional arguments. So executed is with Windows installed to `C:\Windows` and full qualified file name of batch file being `C:\Temp\Test.bat`:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir "C:\Temp\" /A-D /B 2>nul | C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /X /V /C:"!clear.bat" /C:".gitignore" /C:"BookFlight.c" /C:"CheckItinerary.c" /C:"combined_TS1.c" /C:"pre_cci.c" /C:"TS1.prm" /C:"TS1.usr" /C:"vuser_end.c" /C:"vuser_init.c" /C:"globals.h" /C:"ScriptUploadMetadata.xml" /C:"Test.bat"
```

**DIR** outputs to handle **STDOUT** (standard output)

- just the names of files because of option `/A-D` (attribute not directory)
- matching the default wildcard pattern `*` (any file name)
- found in specified directory `C:\Temp`
- in bare format because of option `/B` which means just file name and file extension.

It is not really possible that command **DIR** outputs an error message in this case because of no directory entry found matching these criteria to handle **STDERR** (standard error) as there must be the batch file in this directory. But `2>nul` would redirect this error message to handle **STDERR** of the command process started in background to suppress it.

The output of **DIR** is redirected with `|` to **STDIN** (standard input) of **FINDSTR** which searches

- case-insensitive because of option `/I`
- and literally because of option `/L`
- for lines which completely match because of option `/X`
- one of the search strings specified with the options `/C:`
- and outputs to handle **STDOUT** of background command process the inverted result because of option `/V` which means all lines NOT being completely ANY of the searched strings.

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with `findstr` with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** captures the output to handle **STDOUT** of background command process and processes this output line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself after finishing execution of the command line.

**FOR** skips all empty lines which do not occur here. **FOR** would next split up each line into substrings using the characters normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters. A line would be ignored by **FOR** on first substring starting with `;` being the default end of line character. Otherwise just the first space/tab delimited string would be assigned to loop variable `I` for further processing.

This line splitting behavior is not wanted here as file names can contain one or more spaces and can start with a semicolon after 0 or more leading spaces. For that reason option `eol=|` is used to define vertical bar as end of line character which no file name can contain ever and option `delims=` is used to define an empty list of string delimiters to turn off splitting the file names up into substrings.

Therefore each file name output by **DIR** not being one of the strings specified as search strings for **FINDSTR** is assigned completely to the loop variable `I` and **FOR** executes the command **DEL** which deletes the file independent on being a hidden file because of using option `/A` and even on being a read-only file because of option `/F`.

The command line rewritten for using **FINDSTR** with regular expressions to filter out file names matching one of the search patterns:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "BatchFileName=%~nx0"
set "BatchFileName=%BatchFileName:.=\.%"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0" /A-D /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /X /V /C:"!clear\.bat" /C:"\.gitignore" /C:"^.*\.usr" /C:"default\.cfg" /C:"default\.usp" /C:"^.*\.c" /C:"^.*lobals\.h" /C:"^.*custom_body\.h" /C:"^.*body_variables\.txt" /C:"^.*ploadMetadata\.xml" /C:"^.*\.prm" /C:"%BatchFileName%"') do @del /A /F "%~dp0%%I"
endlocal
```

**Note:** **FINDSTR** option `/R` is used instead of `/L` for a regular expression search which requires `.` being escaped with `\` to be interpreted as literal character and `*` being modified to `^.*` to match any character from beginning of line 0 or more times.

The same can be achieved with batch file name not containing a space character also by using:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "BatchFileName=%~nx0"
set "BatchFileName=%BatchFileName:.=\.%"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0" /A-D /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /X /V "!clear\.bat \.gitignore ^.*\.usr default\.cfg default\.usp ^.*\.c ^.*lobals\.h ^.*custom_body\.h ^.*body_variables\.txt ^.*ploadMetadata\.xml ^.*\.prm %BatchFileName%"') do @del /A /F "%~dp0%%I"
endlocal
```

**FINDSTR** interprets a space in a search string specified with just `"..."` as OR expression while a space in a search string specified with `/C:"..."` is interpreted literally as space character.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 which is always the full path of the batch file currently executed by Windows command processor and ending always with a backslash and `%~nx0` ... file name with extension of the batch file.
- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 0):

The help of this command may be put you on the right direction [findstr /?](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

`/G:StringsFile` Get search string from a file (/ stands for console).

You need to put all your strings into a file and use this syntax :

`findstr /G:"Filter_File.txt"`

`/V   Print only lines that do NOT contain a match.`

`/I   Case-insensitive search.`

So you can write something like that :

```bat
@echo off
Title Batch script delete files when file name does not match list of patterns
Set "Files2Keep=%~dp0Files2Keep.txt"

>"%Files2Keep%" (
    echo    !clear.bat
    echo    .gitignore
    echo    BookFlight.c
    echo    CheckItinerary.c
    echo    combined_TS1.c
    echo    pre_cci.c
    echo    TS1.prm
    echo    TS1.usr
    echo    vuser_end.c
    echo    vuser_init.c
    echo    globals.h
    echo    ScriptUploadMetadata.xml
)

@for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a:-d ^|findstr /I /V /G:"%Files2Keep%"') do ( 
    If "%%~nxa" NEQ "%~nx0" (
        IF "%%~dpnxa" NEQ "%Files2Keep%" (
            Echo DEL /s /q "%%a"
        )
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: This deletes everything, icluding Files2Keep.txt file

Comment: This fails, because every file is deleted, nothing is kept.

Comment: @AndrewKozyrev I edited the answer to keep the file `Files2Keep.txt` not to be deleted !

Comment: This is the result:

DEL /s /q ".gitignore"
...
It still deletes everything.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the information you've provided, and that which is available inside `.gitignore`, I would suggest you use an ignore list, adding a few of your own.

I assume that `!clear.bat` is the file you're seeking help with, so I'd offer this as its content.

```batch-file
@CD /D "%~dp0"
@For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B /S /A:D') Do @RD /S /Q "%%G"
@(Del /A /F /Q *.bak *.c.pickle *.ci *.dat *.db *.idx *.sdf combined_*.c ^
 Breakpoints.xml CompilerLogMetadata.xml logfile.log mdrv.log mdrv_cmd.txt ^
 options.txt output.txt pre_cci.c ReplaySummaryReport.xml ThumbnailsCache.tmp ^
 UserTasks.xml)
```

You'll note, *as previously mentioned*, that whilst you're wanting to keep `.c` files, both `combined_*.c` and `pre_cci.c` are created during compilation and not required. If you wish to keep them, please remove them from lines `3` and `5` as necessary.

Comment: Failed: didn't remove "some_file.txt"

Comment: @AndrewKozyrev, that file definitely doesn't exist in your current file listing image, and most certainly didn't in your previous image either. I specifically mentioned it was based upon the ignore list, adding a few of your own. I then used the list provided in your linked image, to add a few of your own for you. I cannot have been expected to know which files existed, outside of the information you provided! Just add `*.txt` to the list!

Comment: Your solution is not filtering files, it iterates through file names, hardcoded, to delete, not file names to ignore.
But thanks a lot, I appreciate it!

Comment: I know, that's what I told you it did! Only an absolute fool would create and post a script which permanently deletes all files like that. This method deletes only those which are known not to be required, because they're listed in `.gitignore`, or because you've specifically mentiond them in your question or its accompanying image!

Comment: I wrote `.gitignore` with **`!`** to list the files to keep. It does not list the files to ignore, rather to keep.

Comment: I used the recommended `.gitignore` information from `loadrunner`, to ensure that only the files listed in there as not necessary, were deleted. Any other's I listed were based purely upon your exact provided list. It was unnecessary and would have been rude of me, to just supply a `findstr` listing, as the other two answers already did that, so I provided the opposite logic. If you don't like it, or don't want to do that, then that's your perogative, but the method I used was fair in that it does not delete files which must remain, and removes the `data` and `result[0123456789]*` directories.

Comment: I do like your solution for being different from the other two. Thank you a lot for your time and effort, I'm really grateful.